# Using \input to insert Tikz-code from another file: nested input cause wider border each time called?

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins, input

I am having a project in which I use Tikz for making my graphics. I "externalize" the coding by using a tikz-editor. I then simply save the achieved tikz-code in a separate `.tex` file in which only stands

```
\begin{tikz} <> \end{tikz}
```

I wrap this code inside a `figure` environment combined with `\resizebox` and by using `\insert`. I want that the picture directly starts at the left shown border and go completely to the right. However, (maybe because of nested `\input`?) every time I call `\input`, the image is having a wider margin to the right.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[showframe,includeheadfoot, left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\noindent native tikz-code:\\
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (10,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{figure}

\noindent input 1x:\\
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\input{rectangle.tex}
}
\end{figure}

\noindent input 2x:\\
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\input{rectangle_nested.tex}
}
\end{figure}

\noindent input 3x:\\
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\input{rectangle_nested_2.tex}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this, results in this image:

[image]

Including a `.pdf` via `\includegraphics` works, however I don't use the precompiled version, as I have to rerun the code from my main-file for creating citations I use in the graphic etc. So I just want to include the tikz-commands from an external file but not creating any margins. Many thanks.

EDIT: `rectangle.tex` just contains the tikz-code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (10,.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and `rectangle_nested.tex` just:

```
\input{rectangle.tex}
```

Comment: You have spurious spaces after `\input`. `\resizebox` is taking those spaces into account.

Comment: How can I delete those spaces?

Comment: Put a `%` after every `\input`: `\input{whatever}%`. New lines are treated like spaces.

Comment: Oh after \input I just put a % and this seems to solve it

Comment: `\noindent native tikz-code:\\` never use `\\ ` before a `figure` also you should almost never need `\noindent` in a latex document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[New lines are treated like spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/82917) (reduced MWE with just one example):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[red] (0,0) rectangle (10,.5);
\end{tikzpicture} % <-- HERE THERE IS A SPACE
}

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{% <-- This is good!
\input{rectangle.tex} % <-- HERE THERE IS A SPACE
}
\end{document}
```

As a matter of fact, you correctly used `%` after opening the brace for the third argument of `\resizebox`.

Comment: are you sure about not needing `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}` ? I see a difference of `\glue 3.65 plus 1.825 minus 1.21666` in the output if I add a `%` there.

Comment: Uhm, I thought so, but now I'm not so sure...

Comment: I am sure :-)...

Comment: Can't test now but I trust you `:-)`.